# Row Reducing Matrix with Complex Entries

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers

I was just wondering how you would row reduce this matrix. Do you need to multiply the bottom by the complex conjugate?

$$\begin{bmatrix} -1 & i \\ -i & -1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Just follow your normal steps for reducing rows. When you need to do arithmetic follow the rules for complex number arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & i \\
-i & -1\\
\end{pmatrix} \xrightarrow{\text{add ($-i\ \times$ row $1$) to (row $2$)}}
&\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & i \\
-i + (-i\times -1) & -1 + (-i\times i)\\
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & i \\
0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix} \xrightarrow{\text{multiply (row $1$) by $-1$}} 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -i \\
0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}